# PHP DOM replacing tag src doesn't work

Tags: php, dom

I have been trying to get the HTML of an external website and look through it with PHP. I want to show images from the site, so I tried changing img sources from `/assets/img/example.png` to `www.example.com/assets/img/example.png` by getting the current src attribute like so (after getting each image from the document):

`$current_src = $img->getAttribute("src");`

and then assigning the `current_src` to the image along with the main URL. But this puts the new image in `<noscript>` tags like this:

```
<img data-cfsrc="http://www.example.com"><noscript><img src="/assets/img/example.png></noscript>
```

**EDIT:**
A simple example of what I am doing is here (just for the first image):

`$test_img = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img')[1];
$test_img->setAttribute("src", "http://www.example.com" . $test_img->getAttribute("src"));
echo $test_img->getAttribute("src");`

And this echoes `http://www.example.com/assets/img/logo-bar.png`, but when I go back to the view source I see that it is in a seperate tag like this:

`<img style="display:none;visibility:hidden;" data-cfsrc="/assets/img/logo-bar.png" alt="example Logo"><noscript><img src="http://www.example.com/assets/img/logo-bar.png" alt="example Logo"></noscript>`

What causes this? And how can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: You should post more code, we can't guess what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

You should use '`.`' to combin a string (`www.example.com`) with `$current_src`.

```
$current_src = $img->getAttribute("src"); // /assets/img/example.png
$new_current_src = 'www.example.com'.$current_src;
```

Comment: Would I use this same code if I did not know what the image attribute of src is, and how would I do it?

Comment: Do you have new scr ?

Comment: No, I'm wondering if I could change the source of many images without having to manually type out their sources

Comment: what is your _output_ when used `$current_src = $img->getAttribute("src");` ?? In other word, if echo $current_src, what will be printed ?

Comment: echoed $current_src (this is the first of many): `/assets/img/logo-bar.png`

Comment: All right, Now you should put `www.example.com` in the first of `$current_src`. In other word you should combine `www.example.com` with `$current_src` (/assets/img/logo-bar.png). To do this, you can use  '`.`' something like this: `'www.example.com'.$current_src;`